# Vlookup Multiple sheets using reference

Tags: excel, vba

I have 8 sheets with Multiple columns data , i want these 7 sheets vlookup with sheet8 and what ever the ids are there in sheet8 should be present in all 7 sheets remaining row should be deleted.

the code is below what i have but its not working proerly still i can see some id with #N/A present in the data.

```
Sub delete()

    Dim arr(), msg As String
    Dim c As Range
    Dim ws_lrow, ws8_lrow, i As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    ws8_lrow = Sheets("Sheet8").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    ReDim arr(ws8_lrow)

    For i = 2 To ws8_lrow
        arr(i - 2) = Sheets("Sheet8").Cells(i, 1).Value
    Next i

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        ws_lrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

        For Each c In ws.Range("B2:B" & ws_lrow)
            If IsInArray(c, arr()) = 0 Then
                msg = msg & "User '" & c & "' from: " & ws.Name & vbCrLf
                c.EntireRow.delete xlShiftUp
            End If
        Next c
    Next ws

    MsgBox "The following users have been deleted:" & vbCrLf & msg

End Sub

Private Function IsInArray(valToBeFound As Variant, arr As Variant) As Boolean

    Dim element As Variant
    On Error GoTo IsInArrayError: 'array is empty
       For Each element In arr
            If element = valToBeFound Then
                IsInArray = True
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next element
    Exit Function

IsInArrayError:
    On Error GoTo 0
    IsInArray = False

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You are comitting a classical mistake when iterating over a range of rows, top down, and deleting rows throughout the process. In this type of situation the easiest and correct way is to loop *from the bottom up*. This loop should be fixed:

```
'For Each c In ws.Range("B2:B" & ws_lrow)
'    If IsInArray(c, arr()) = 0 Then
'        msg = msg & "User '" & c & "' from: " & ws.Name & vbCrLf
'        c.EntireRow.delete
'    End If
'Next c
```

Loop from the bottom up like this:

```
For i = ws_lrow to 2 step -1
    If IsInArray(ws.Range("B" & i).value, arr) = 0 Then
        msg = msg & "User '" & ws.Range("B" & i).value & "' from: " & ws.Name & vbCrLf
        ws.Rows(i).delete
    End If
Next i
```